# TabNavigator in StackNavigator and con't to push a new page

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

React Navigation
1.x

with ***Redux***

my StackNavigator:

```
export const MyAppStackNavigator = StackNavigator({
    ......
}, {
    initialRouteName: "TabBase",
    navigationOptions: ({navigation, screenProps}) => {
    },
    transitionConfig: () => ({
        screenInterpolator: CardStackStyleInterpolator.forHorizontal
    })
});
```

and my TabNavigator (AppTabNavigator):

```
const AppTabNavigator = TabNavigator(
    {
        Page1: {
            screen: Page1,
        },
    },
    {}
)

export default class TabBase extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View styles={{
                flex: 1
            }} >
                <AppTabNavigator/>
            </View>
        )    
    }
}
```

in the **Page1** a button onPress will push a new Page

```
this.props.navigation.navigate("Page2");
```

but it's not work.

if **MyAppStackNavigator**  set `initialRouteName: "AppTabNavigator"`

```
this.props.navigation.navigate("Page2");
```

is working.

but I need in TabBase do some other thing, how should I do, let button working ?

Comment: Where does Page2 resides ? In tab or in the stack ? I believe it resides in Stack. Is it so ?

Comment: @SurajMalviya in Stack